# Run bat file in Java and wait

Tags: java, batch-file, exec

You would think that launching a bat file from Java would be an easy task but no... I have a bat file that does some sql commands for a loop of values read from a text file. It is more or less like this:

```
FOR /F %%x in (%CD%\listOfThings.txt) do sqlcmd -Slocalhost\MSSQL %1 %2 -d %3 -i %CD%\SQLScripts\\%%x
exit
```

Don't worry about the specifics they are not important. What i want is to simply run this bat file from within Java and have it wait until execution is finished. Apparently it is not easy. What i have so far is this:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /K start SQLScriptsToRun.bat"
                    +" -U"+getUser()
                    +" -P"+getPass()
                    +" " + projectName);
return true;
```

The problem is that the exec() method returns immediately. The bat file runs for a good 2-3 minutes. I tried removing the start but to no avail. I tried many variations but it got me nowhere. Any ideas on how to do this simple task?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should not ignore the return value of [`.exec()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String[])). It gives you a [`Process`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) object that you can [`waitFor()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor()), like this:

```
final Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("blahblahblah");
final int exitVal = process.waitFor();
// if exitVal == 0, the command succeeded
```

Answer (score 7):

you need to use `waitFor` on the process `exec` call returns.

Comment: thanks it wworked but mmyers beat you by 2 seconds and gave an example :P +1 though

Comment: @Savvas: Actually he beat me by 24 seconds, but maybe that was because of the example... :)

Comment: :) i wish i could give you 2+ then :P