# How do we execute Batch files from Java

Tags: java, process, batch-file, runtime.exec

I need to execute a batch file from my Java Program. I found multiple threads related to this query. 
[Execute Batch File from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/615948/how-do-i-run-a-batch-file-from-my-java-application)

In addition to the above information, I need to know if that operation was executed successfully or not. Is it possible to get a handle to that from Java?

Answer (score 3):

Both Runtime.exec() and ProcessBuilder.start() return a Process object.

With that, you can use Process.getExitValue(). That said, I don't happen to know if the shell's exit value is the same as the script's.

Comment: I tried that. But I'm getting the following exceptin.Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException: process has not exited
 at java.lang.ProcessImpl.exitValue(Native Method)
 at com.mt.test.TestClass2.main(TestClass2.java:13)

Comment: I think this thread should solve my problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448402/run-bat-file-in-java-and-wait-2

Comment: Check out http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html  Specifically, the method waitFor().

Answer (score 2):

You should check out [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).

I highly recommend it. It will probably answer your next 4-5 questions.

Answer (score 0):

Use java.lang.ProcessBuilder to create the call to the batch file. The Process object will allow you to monitor the output and the exit code from the batch file. A non-zero exit code typically indicates failure.

Comment: I think this thread should solve my problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448402/run-bat-file-in-java-and-wait-2

Answer (score 0):

You should really check [Commons Exec](http://commons.apache.org/exec/tutorial.html). It will help you getting the output from the batch file, and setting a timeout, and even creating the command line.