# How to execute a batch file that takes user input from a java program and have java wait for batch to close

Tags: java, batch-file, cmd, executable-jar

I need to have a runnable jar start one batch file, then run some java code, then run a second batch file in that order, but both batch files get executed at the same time.

I start the jar as follows from a command line (the param isn't relevant to the batch files though):

```
java -jar "pathToJar" "param"
```

My first batch file stops 2 services:

```
@echo off 
SET /P service1=Enter service1 name:
net stop %service1%
SET /P service2=Enter service2 name:
net stop %service2%
exit
```

Then I have java code running that requires the above services to be stopped (hence being run after).

Then the second batch file copies files:

```
@echo off
robocopy <SRC> <DEST> /e /COPY:DAT
exit
```

I am executing both of these batch files as follows (two of these blocks with the java code between them):

```
PrintWriter batch;
try {
  //Prepare batch file
  String batPath = projectRoot+ File.separator + "services.bat";
  batch = new PrintWriter(batPath);
  String batch_content = "@echo off" 
      + "\r\nSET /P service1=Enter service1 name:"
      + "\r\nnet stop %service1%"
      + "\r\nSET /P service2=Enter service2 name:"
      + "\r\nnet stop %service2%"
      + "\r\nexit";
  batch.println(batch_content);
  batch.close();

  //Run batch file
  ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "\"\"", "start", "services.bat");
  File dir = new File(projectRoot);
  pb.directory(dir);
  Process p = pb.start();
  int exitVal = p.waitFor();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
} catch (IOException e) {
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
}
```

The problem I'm having is that the first batch file starts, then the java code runs before the first batch file finishes executing, then subsequently the second batch file runs.

I've read in other [threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448402/run-bat-file-in-java-and-wait-2) that using the 'start' parameter in the process is what causes this (since the process object can't read the new cmd instance).
I've tried changing this to

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "services.bat");
```

But this way the cmd window that I ran the jar from just hangs on a blank new line and doesn't prompt for the service name as expected.
I've also tried with a `/k` instead of `/c` but that didn't change anything.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you tried just calling the batch file by itself? `.bat` and `.cmd` is associated by cmd.exe by default. so try `ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("services.bat");`

Comment: also consider making java wait for the process `final int exitVal = process.waitFor();`

Comment: @GerhardBarnard If I remove the "cmd" and "/c" parameters, it acts exactly the same way, returning an exit value of 2.
Also if you look at the code I provided, you can see that I do have the line `int exitVal = p.waitFor();`